# How to implement .N of data.table in H2O, in R?

Tags: r, data.table, h2o

Consider the following code.

```
library(data.table)

data1x <- "x row1
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
4 2"

data1 <- read.table(textConnection(data1x), header=TRUE)
setDT(data1)
data1[, seqN := 1:.N, by="x"]
```

I want to do similar thing on h2o data frame. I went through the user manual, but am not able to figure out how to do  this using h20.

**EDIT :** I tried the below code, for h2o, but it is giving error :

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
data1x <- "x row1
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
4 2"
data1x <- read.table(textConnection(data1x), header=TRUE)
data1xH2O <- as.h2o(data1x)

fun = function(df) {
  1:nrow(df)
}

h2o.ddply(data1xH2O, "x", fun)
```

This results in following error :

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Rapids)

water.rapids.Rapids.IllegalASTException
 [1] "water.rapids.Rapids$IllegalASTException: Missing a number"                                                   
 [2] "    water.rapids.Rapids.number(Rapids.java:312)"                                                             
 [3] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNumList(Rapids.java:243)"                                                       
 [4] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseList(Rapids.java:208)"                                                          
 [5] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:140)"                                                          
 [6] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionDefinition(Rapids.java:193)"                                            
 [7] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:139)"                                                          
 [8] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionApplication(Rapids.java:158)"                                           
 [9] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:138)"                                                          
[10] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionApplication(Rapids.java:158)"                                           
[11] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:138)"                                                          
[12] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parse(Rapids.java:48)"                                                               
[13] "    water.rapids.Rapids.exec(Rapids.java:81)"                                                                
[14] "    water.api.RapidsHandler.exec(RapidsHandler.java:39)"                                                     
[15] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                             
[16] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                           
[17] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                   
[18] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)"                                                        
[19] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:61)"                                                               
[20] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:412)"                                                   
[21] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:263)"                                               
[22] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:200)"                                                  
[23] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                            
[24] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                            
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                  
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                              
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)"                           
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)"                             
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)"                       
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                      
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                               
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)"                        
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                       
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                           
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[37] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                 
[38] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"          
[39] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"           
[40] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                
[41] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"
[42] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                        
[43] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                   
[44] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                  
[45] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"            
[46] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                        
[47] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                         
[48] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"                                                                   

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Missing a number
```

Any suggestion, what I can do to remove this error.

Comment: **In case If not possible** then you can **convert h2o data frame to R data frame** using `as.data.frame` command. You can run above code by converting h2o data frame to R data frame using h2o.

Comment: No, i need to transfer my data.table logic to H2O.

Comment: Means you want to implement some logic inside above code using h2o. Right ??

Comment: Yes, similar like the output with data.table code, but using H2O.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see this question first however in the following answer fun1 and fun2 are creating the same sequence based on column name you choose.

[How to use : function in H2O ddply, R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821274/how-to-use-function-in-h2o-ddply-r)

is that you are looking for?