# How to use : function in H2O ddply, R?

Tags: r, h2o

Consider the below code :

```
library(h2o)
library(plyr)

h2o.init()
data1x <- "x row1
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
4 2"
data1x <- read.table(textConnection(data1x), header=TRUE)
data1xH2O <- as.h2o(data1x)

fun = function(df) {
  1:2
}

h2o.ddply(data1xH2O, "x", fun)

ddply(data1x, "x", fun)
```

The h20 version of ddply gives below error.

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Rapids)

water.rapids.Rapids.IllegalASTException
 [1] "water.rapids.Rapids$IllegalASTException: Missing a number"                                                   
 [2] "    water.rapids.Rapids.number(Rapids.java:312)"                                                             
 [3] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNumList(Rapids.java:243)"                                                       
 [4] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseList(Rapids.java:208)"                                                          
 [5] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:140)"                                                          
 [6] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionDefinition(Rapids.java:193)"                                            
 [7] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:139)"                                                          
 [8] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionApplication(Rapids.java:158)"                                           
 [9] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:138)"                                                          
[10] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseFunctionApplication(Rapids.java:158)"                                           
[11] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parseNext(Rapids.java:138)"                                                          
[12] "    water.rapids.Rapids.parse(Rapids.java:48)"                                                               
[13] "    water.rapids.Rapids.exec(Rapids.java:81)"                                                                
[14] "    water.api.RapidsHandler.exec(RapidsHandler.java:39)"                                                     
[15] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                             
[16] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                           
[17] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                   
[18] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)"                                                        
[19] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:61)"                                                               
[20] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:412)"                                                   
[21] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:263)"                                               
[22] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:200)"                                                  
[23] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                            
[24] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                            
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                  
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                              
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)"                           
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)"                             
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)"                       
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                      
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                               
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)"                        
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                       
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                           
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[36] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[37] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                 
[38] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"          
[39] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"           
[40] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                
[41] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"
[42] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                        
[43] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                   
[44] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                  
[45] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"            
[46] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                        
[47] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                         
[48] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"                                                                   

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 

ERROR MESSAGE:

Missing a number
```

The same code for ddply from plyr package works.
Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Your function seems to be incorrect. You need to change it and try. I have changed the function body to `sum(df[,1], na.rm = TRUE)/nrow(df)` than it works without error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function does nothing with respect the dataframe and based on your function definition it is not clear what your objective is.

fun = function(df) {
  1:2
}

if you look at h2o.ddply function documentation you will see that this function is used to apply a function on full data set based on certain criteria.

I have changed your above example as below to explain it better:

```
> data1xH2O
   x row1
 1 1    1  
 2 1    2
 3 1    3
 4 1    4
 5 2    1
 6 2    2
 > fun1 = function(df) { df[,1]}
 > h2o.ddply(data1xH2O, 1:2, fun1)
     x row1 ddply_C1
   1 1    1        1
   2 1    2        1
   3 1    3        1
   4 1    4        1
   5 2    1        2
   6 2    2        2
```

Above the fun1 is extracting our column out from passed dataframe. Again if I change the fun to fun2 as below:

```
 > fun2 = function(df) { df[,2]}
 > h2o.ddply(data1xH2O, 1:2, fun2)
     x row1 ddply_C1
   1 1    1        1
   2 1    2        2
   3 1    3        3
   4 1    4        4
   5 2    1        1
   6 2    2        2
```